# Android ImageView pan animation with scaleType centerCrop

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, android-animation, pan

I have an `ImageView` set to `scaleType="centerCrop"` , I am trying to create an animation which pans this `ImageView` to its left and right edges, which are outside of the bounds of the view. 
How would I do this?

Normally when animating I have the full view on screen already, but in this case the ImageView itself is rendered but its source is scaled outside the bounds of its view. So if I was just animating the VIEW itself I won't be accessing the source.

This may have something more to do with animating on a canvas within an imageview, instead of moving the X, Y position of the imageview itself. Insight appreciated

Regarding the "too broad" allegation to close this question, yeah, it isn't.

Comment: One way to do this is through manipulating the ImageView's image Matrix, although it's a little complicated and not very well documented. This is a very similar problem to making an imageview where you can zoom in and pan on touch gestures. So you can maybe try to find online source code for those, then modify it to work as an animation (for example AsyncTask) instead of onTouch. Such as this: https://github.com/judepereira/android-multitouch/blob/master/src/com/multitouch/example/MultiTouch.java

Comment: @Gak2 good suggestion, I think I am using some code similar to that in another part of this app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to do this with the KenBurnsView library object

https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView

I modified my version to use my custom imageview objects which extend NetworkImageView from Volley